# Error when changing or resetting FBProfilePictureView profileId

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have programmatically added an `FBProfilePictureView` object to a view. When initially logging in, the user's profile picture displays as expected when setting the profileId of the object within the `FBLoginViewDelegate` method `loginViewFetchedUserInfo:user:`. However, when logging off the following line of code produces an error:

```
profilePicture.profileId = nil;
```

The error thrown is:

```
[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Note: This was only an issue after I incrementally upgraded the iOS SDK from 3.5 to 3.8.

If anyone has encountered this issue, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to clear out the FBProfilePictureView manually. When you logoff the image gets cleared. Look at the Scrumptious example that comes with the sdk. When the user goes to settings and logoff the images are cleared. You can hide the view if you don't want to see a stock image.